# How do Midi-chlorians communicate with the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, midichlorians

In wookiepedia it states that Midi-chlorians communicate the will of the force to the Jedi, so how do they get the information that the Midi-chlorians send to them?

Comment: Please cite original sources, not Wookieepedia.

Comment: How do you figure that out please help I want to give credit were it’s due